# Ads on a facebook app (game) page

Tags: facebook, adsense, ads

I am working on a facebook application a game and was wondering how to monetize it. I am new to FB and even the ad market place. What is my best bet to get ad revenue? I mean, which provider should I use? Can I use adsense? What are my options? Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In reaction to a little adverse privacy publicity (see: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/10/18/facebook_apps_privacy_breach/ ) Facebook tightened up their advertising policy around privacy and created an official approved ad provider list here:  http://developers.facebook.com/adproviders/ listing ad providers who have agreed to comply with Facebook's privacy policies.

I recently did some searches in the Facebook Developer forums and found that RockYou and LifeStreet Media seem to be the most frequently cited providers.

AdSense is not currently on this list, but many apps do use AdSense.

Currently there is Fear, Uncertainty, and Doubt (FUD) over whether using AdSense in a Facebook app will get your account closed by AdSense, and whether it will get your app banned by Facebook.

Those who believe AdSense might ban you frequently assert that AdSense prohibits ad placement in an iframe, which is the only way to do it as a Facebook app.  I have read the AdSense terms and can find no reference to iframes being prohibited.  AdSense does expect your page to have meaningful content, which would seem to preclude use in some games or other apps that lack text content (think pure flash apps)

Comment: Thanks for that information. Had no idea facebook has a list of approved ad providers. But are these any good? Do you know how effective they are? In fact it might make sense for me to use something like Tapjoy as mine is a game and so not much text for adsense to show ads using.

Comment: I think it depends on your app.  I had very good results with AdSense (much much higher revenue than Cubics, RockYou, etc.) but my app was a content-centric app with a tight niche market.  The AdSense ads were highly relevant.  The "approved Facebook ad providers" do not seem to do any contextual targeting and seem pretty heavy on dating and Facebook game ads.  Their ads are often styled to look like part of Facebook however which should yield higher click through rates.